# Geolocation not working on iphone

Tags: javascript, geolocation

I have tried to get my coordinates on an iphoen using the javascript GEOlocation aPI but it just doesn't work. Here is a simple example I tested, http://mapscripting.com/how-to-use-geolocation-in-mobile-safari, and an alert pops up and says 'could not find location'

I have tried various other example from around the web and nothing works. Please help, it's driving me nuts.

Answer (score 1):

Sorted. Safari Location settings was turned off. I have never touched this setting so worried that other people have this off by default and there is no way to check this with javascript as far as I know.

Answer (score 0):

'Could not find location' on iOS means that your device currently cannot connect to the GPS satellite.

Try going outside maybe...? ;)

Comment: Tried but no luck. Quite frustrating since it seems to have worked for some people.